# Can I bypass cache in OpenCL?

Tags: caching, opencl, gpgpu

I have actually never met a case that I would need the value I wrote to global memory be cached. But I can find no way to stop GPU from polluting the cache as I can do on a CPU by using non-temporal writes.

It's a serious problem that can drop the performance by 20% or more.

Comment: If you want to reuse whatever value you just put into global memory then use the value you already hold in private memory. Calling the global value again makes another read, since nothing ensures a work item the value has not been changed since it wrote to it. There is actually no cache involved.

Comment: @DarkZeros So why outputting one sum of the results of a whole work group will result in higher cache hit rate than outputting result of each work item?

Comment: using pure global memory for xyz coordinates in simple nbody kernel gave comparable performance to local memory optimized one. Performance ratio was similar to local/cache bandwidth ratios. This could be cache's job but I didn't check LLVM output so I'm not sure. xyz data was 768kB so could fit in L2 cache.

Answer (score 2):

There is little recent info about this, but what makes you think writes are cached at all? Unless you are using atomic operations, the GPU does not care about coherency. If you read a memory location after you write into it, you get undefined results even within the same work group, unless you put a global memory barrier in between the operations. That means caching the written value is pointless, because at that point all of your shader executions must have already written their data. You can be sure that won't fit in any cache!
GPU is a completely different beast than CPUs are. Concepts found in one don't easily translate to the other.

These are just my assumptions, which could be wrong, but what I'm sure of is that vendors try their best to optimize their GPUs for the currently most common operations done on them, just so they can boast by achieving a little higher FPS in current titles than the competition. Trying to outsmart them is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Actually it is written in the document that writes are cached on a GCN GPU. And writes can reduce cache hit rate from 90% to 50%. I agree that caching writes is pointless on a GPU unless you have temporary result that can't fit in neither registers nor LDS which is uncommon. So I think there maybe a way to by pass cache for writes. There are cache policies exist in the instruction set anyway (I didn't dig into it though.)...